# Find a quote that contains a specific word from many quotes in the same line using regex

Tags: regex

If I have different quotes in the same line, How can I find the quote that contains a specific word using regex? For example If I have these 3 lines:

> "MacOs is good"  "Linux is good".
>
> "MacOs is bad" "Linux is bad".
>
> "MacOs is perfect" "Linux is perfect".

How can I get the quotes that contains Linux which mean these:

> "Linux is good"
>
> "Linux is bad"
>
> "Linux is perfect"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following regex pattern:

```regex
"[^"]*\bLinux\b[^"]*"
```

### Demo

**Explanation of regex:**

```
"          match opening double quote
[^"]*      zero or more content before Linux
\bLinux\b  match Linux
[^"]*      zero or more content after Linux
"          closing double quote
```

Note that my answer assumes that your input text would only have proper balanced double quotes.  If not, then my answer could throw some false positives.